# Trying to find the coldest and hottest Cities in an array of objects

Tags: javascript, arrays, javascript-objects

```
// function
function findColdHot(array) {
  // create an empty object
  var resultObj = {};
  // create coldest and hottest variables
  let coldest = Infinity
  let hottest = -Infinity
  // iterate over the array
  for (let i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
    if (array[i].temp > hottest) {
      hottest = array[i].city;
    } else if (array[i].temp < coldest) {
      coldest = array[i].city;
    }
  }
  // create coldest and hottest properties
  resultObj['Coldest Place'] = coldest
  resultObj['Hottest Place'] = hottest;
  // return result object
  return resultObj;
}
// tests
var input = [
  {city: 'Helsinki', temp: 12},
  {city: 'Berlin', temp: 10},
  {city: 'Oslo', temp: 4},
  {city: 'Nairobi', temp: 39},
  {city: 'Paris', temp: 6},
  {city: 'Istanbul', temp: 39},
  {city: 'Rome', temp: 25}
];
var actual = findColdHot(input);
var expected = {'Coldest Place': 'Oslo', 'Hottest Place': 'Nairobi'};
console.log(actual)
```

Im trying to figure out how to use a for loop and get the coldest and hottest cities.
i've also tried changing coldest and hottest variables to:

```
let coldest = array.[0].temp
let hottest = array[0].temp
```

and then starting the for loop i = 1 but it still doesn't work

instead of getting the expected output i get:

```
{ 'Coldest Place': 'Berlin', 'Hottest Place': 'Helsinki' }
```

OR

```
{ 'Coldest Place': 'Berlin', 'Hottest Place': 'Nairobi' }
```

Any help would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

I have made some changes in existing code, now it is working

```
// function
function findColdHot(array) {
  // create an empty object
  var resultObj = {};
  // create coldest and hottest variables
  let coldest = array[0];
  let hottest = array[0];
  // iterate over the array
  for (let i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
    if (array[i].temp > hottest.temp) {
      hottest = array[i];
    } else if (array[i].temp < coldest.temp) {
      coldest = array[i];
    }
  }
  // create coldest and hottest properties
  resultObj['Coldest Place'] = coldest.city;
  resultObj['Hottest Place'] = hottest.city;
  // return result object
  return resultObj;
}
// tests
var input = [
  {city: 'Helsinki', temp: 12},
  {city: 'Berlin', temp: 10},
  {city: 'Oslo', temp: 4},
  {city: 'Nairobi', temp: 39},
  {city: 'Paris', temp: 6},
  {city: 'Istanbul', temp: 39},
  {city: 'Rome', temp: 25}
];
var actual = findColdHot(input);
var expected = {'Coldest Place': 'Oslo', 'Hottest Place': 'Nairobi'};
console.log(actual)
```

Comment: is it ok if we start the for loop at i = 0? i thought we had to start at i = 1 since were comparing array[0] to index 1 and beyond? Wouldn't the elements get compared to themselves at index 0?

Comment: You should explain what you changed and why to add more value to the OP

Answer (score 0):

You define coldest and hottest cities as `Infinity` which I assume it interprets as number. Then you compare this number to string value which is city name.

Make sure that you don't mix variable types, especially in JavaScript.

```
function findColdHot(array) {
  // create an empty object
  var resultObj = {};
  // create coldest and hottest variables
  let coldest = array[0];
  let hottest = array[0];
  
  // iterate over the array
  for (let i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
    if (array[i].temp > hottest.temp) {
      hottest = array[i];
    } else if (array[i].temp < coldest.temp) {
      coldest = array[i];
    }
  }
  // create coldest and hottest properties
  resultObj['Coldest Place'] = coldest.city
  resultObj['Hottest Place'] = hottest.city;
  // return result object
  return resultObj;
}
```